# There is an error in XML document (1, 1) on TFS vNext Build

Tags: azure-pipelines

My builds fils with the folloewing error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

> TFS2017 update 1 Agent version  2.127.0

We have a strange problem on our build server:

```
2018-03-19T13:23:41.9444545Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2018-03-19T13:23:41.9962547Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
2018-03-19T13:23:41.9970401Z Setting environment variable 
TFVC_BUILDAGENT_POLICYPATH
2018-03-19T13:23:41.9971268Z Querying workspace information.
2018-03-19T13:23:43.0915688Z ##[error]There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
2018-03-19T13:23:43.1000481Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
```

If we run the same job again, on the same agent, it run's again without error We did not have these problem with agent with an older version 1.105.6

Comment: Every time the agent initializes a new TFVC job, it updates the workspace mappings. The work folder should contain a set of files that store teh last-known workspace mapping in order to find a suitable existing workspace and to know what changes to make to it. It looks like that file is corrupt or missing. Have you performed an in-place upgrade of the 1.x agent to the 2.x agent (e.g. the work folder is the same or are you installing the agent to a new workfolder location. In the first case, ensuring that all existing workspaces in TFVC are removed may help you get unlocked.

Comment: Can you share additional logs that stand out int he `_diag` folder of the agent? Check both the worker and the agent logs.

Comment: hi i have set the answer i a new answer sorry

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after updating VS to "15.8.5" went through several rounds of trying to update the agents and look through the logs, the offending statement seems to be:

> [2018-09-24 20:10:56Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   File name: 'tf'
>   [2018-09-24 20:10:56Z INFO ProcessInvoker]   Arguments: 'vc workspaces
>   /format:xml
>   /collection:https://tfs.devxxxcatalyst.com/tfs/XXXCollection/
>   /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'

Looked like the issue was with the workspace, I deleted all the work spaces TFS created:

[image]

Reran the build, seems to work now...

Answer (score 0):

Let me spell it out:  You need to `update the build agent`.

[image]

The azure url is in format

> https://[myorganisation].visualstudio.com/[project_name]/_settings/agentqueues

Answer (score -1):

I installed a new agent next to the old one and it has its own work area, I can now perform a rollback.
I have the rollback disabled on the new agent.

I the file with the error: Worker_20180319-132335-utc.log

The files are here: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=A426FE4732C90B65%211438&cid=A426FE4732C90B65